# Calculate correlation coefficient by bootstrapping

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, simulation, correlation, normal-distribution

I'm looking at the correlation between the day of the year that 5 species of bird started moulting their feathers and the numbers of days it took these 5 species to complete the moulting of their feathers.

I've tried to simulate my data in the code below. For each of the 5 species, I have start day for 10 individuals and the durations for 10 individuals. For each species, I calculated the mean start day and mean duration then calculated the correlation across these 5 species.

What I want to do is bootstrap the mean start date and bootstrap the mean duration for each species. I want to repeat this 10,000 times and calculate the correlation coefficient after each repeat. I then want to extract the 0.025, 0.5 and 0.975 quantiles of the 10,000 correlation coefficients.

I got as far as simulating the raw data, but my code quickly got messy once I tried to bootstrap. Can anyone help me with this?

```
# speciesXX_start_day is the day of the year that 10 individuals of birds started moulting their feathers
# speciesXX_duration is the number of days that each individuals bird took to complete the moulting of its feathers
species1_start_day <- as.integer(rnorm(10, 10, 2))
species1_duration <- as.integer(rnorm(10, 100, 2))

species2_start_day <- as.integer(rnorm(10, 20, 2))
species2_duration <- as.integer(rnorm(10, 101, 2))

species3_start_day <- as.integer(rnorm(10, 30, 2))
species3_duration <- as.integer(rnorm(10, 102, 2))

species4_start_day <- as.integer(rnorm(10, 40, 2))
species4_duration <- as.integer(rnorm(10, 103, 2))

species5_start_day <- as.integer(rnorm(10, 50, 2))
species5_duration <- as.integer(rnorm(10, 104, 2))

start_dates <- list(species1_start_day, species2_start_day, species3_start_day, species4_start_day, species5_start_day)
start_duration <- list(species1_duration, species2_duration, species3_duration, species4_duration, species5_duration)

library(plyr)

# mean start date for each of the 5 species
starts_mean <- laply(start_dates, mean)

# mean duration for each of the 5 species
durations_mean <- laply(start_duration, mean)

# correlation between start date and duration
cor(starts_mean, durations_mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

R allows you to resample datasets with the `sample` function. In order to bootstrap you can just take random samples (with replacement) of your original dataset and then recalculate the statistics for each subsample. You can save the intermediate results in a datastructure so that you can process the data afterwards.

A possible example solution for your specific problem is added below. We take 10000 subsamples of size 3 for each of the species, calculate the statistics and then save the results in a list or vector. After the bootstrap we are able to process all the data:

```
nrSamples = 10000;
listOfMeanStart = list(nrSamples)
listOfMeanDuration = list(nrSamples)
correlations <- vector(mode="numeric", length=nrSamples)

for(i in seq(1,nrSamples))
{
  sampleStartDate = sapply(start_dates,sample,size=3,replace=TRUE)
  sampleDurations = sapply(start_duration,sample,size=3,replace=TRUE)

  listOfMeans[[i]] <- apply(sampleStartDate,2,mean) 
  listOfMeanDuration[[i]] <- apply(sampleDurations,2,mean)
  correlations[i] <- cor(listOfMeans[[i]], listOfMeanDuration[[i]])
}

quantile(correlations,c(0.025,.5,0.975))
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code, that's really useful. I'm wondering how I would do the same thing with the `boot` package?

Comment: @luciano I have never used that package before but there is a good tutorial/example here: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html. You basically have to define your correlation calculation function and feed it your data via boot(). Conceptually speaking, it's basically the same process.