# Loop through many pairs of species models to boostrap correlation coefficients in R

Tags: r, for-loop, regression

This question is similar to using cor.test() to get correlation coefficients for many pairs of variables (e.g. [Calculate correlation coefficient by bootstrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086399/calculate-correlation-coefficient-by-bootstrapping) and [for loop with cor.test over many categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175208/for-loop-with-cor-test-over-many-categories)), but here I'm trying to loop through multiple models and get correlation coefficients between models for only 1 variable that I care about. I'm new to bootstrapping and to loops and I'm getting stuck trying to do both at once.

I have 16 models of species caught in fisheries. I only care about one variable (the fishing gear), and I want to bootstrap the regression coefficients for each gear to get a robust estimate of each regression coefficient, and then calculate the correlation coefficient between the different species. I have a loop to do this manually for each species pair, but I want to loop across all the models and output the results to a dataframe, with a column labeling each species pair.

```
library(mgcv) # for GAMs and GAM outputs

## generate random data for species models
num.caught <- sample(x=0:1000, size =50, replace = TRUE) 
year <- sample(x =2000:2010, size=50, replace=TRUE)
gear <- sample(c('net','line','trawl'), 50, replace=TRUE)
species1.dat <- data.frame(num.caught, year, gear)
species1.gam <- gam(num.caught ~ year + gear, data= species1.dat)
#summary(species1.gam)
#species1.gam$coefficients

num.caught <- sample(x=0:100, size =25, replace = TRUE) 
year <- sample(x =2000:2010, size=25, replace=TRUE)
gear <- sample(c('net','line','trawl'), 25, replace=TRUE)
species2.dat <- data.frame(num.caught, year, gear)
species2.gam <- gam(num.caught ~ year + gear, data= species2.dat)

num.caught <- sample(x=0:500, size =30) 
year <- sample(x =2000:2005, size=30, replace=TRUE)
gear <- sample(c('net','line','trawl'), 30, replace=TRUE)
species3.dat <- data.frame(num.caught, year, gear)
species3.gam <- gam(num.caught ~ year + gear, data= species3.dat)

# Make list of all models in environment
spp.names <- grep(".gam", names(.GlobalEnv), value=TRUE)

mod.1 <- species1.gam
mod.2 <- species2.gam
mod.3 <- species3.gam
# etc...

NoSamples <- 1000
CC <- rep(NA, NoSamples)
for(i in 1:NoSamples) {
#get data from a random draw for species 1
Index1 <- grep("gear",names(summary(mod.1)$p.coeff))
Sp1 <- rnorm(summary(mod.1)$p.coeff[Index1],summary(mod.1)$se[Index1])
#now species 2 
Index2 <- grep("gear",names(summary(mod.2)$p.coeff))
Sp2 <- rnorm(summary(mod.2)$p.coeff[Index2],summary(mod.2)$se[Index2])
#now get the correlation coefficient and store it
CC[i] <- cor(Sp1,Sp2)
} 
## the loop works to here, but I would have to manually re-run with every combination of the 16 species

## This should go inside the loop
quants <- tibble::rownames_to_column(data.frame(quantile(CC)), "quantile") %>% rename(quant_val="quantile.CC.") 
df.CC <- data.frame(mean(CC), quants)
# paste names for each species 
df.CC$spp_pair <- paste0(names(mod.1), "_", names(mod.2)) # This is wrong, it pastes all the col names for each model, not the name of the model itself
df.CC.wide <- pivot_wider(data=df.CC, id_cols = c(spp_pair, mean.CC.), 
                          names_from = quantile, names_prefix = "quant",
                          values_from = quant_val)
names(df.CC.wide) <- gsub(pattern = "%", replacement="", x=names(df.CC.wide))
```

Here I could manually rename and bind each results dataframe, but there should be a way to loop through all the models? I think it could also be done with lapply?

```
# The desired output would be a dataframe with 1 row for each species pair, e.g:

spp_pair              mean.CC. quant0 quant25 quant50 quant75 quant100
1 species1_species2    0.940  0.940   0.940   0.940   0.940    0.940
2 species1_species3    0.200  0.180   0.190   0.200   0.210    0.220
3 species2_species3    0.750  0.600   0.700   0.720   0.800    0.810
```

Comment: @RonakShah I'm not sure I did that very efficiently, but I attempted to create some sample models

Answer (score 1):

After running your above code `summary(mod.1)$p.coeff` returns `NULL`. I am not sure if I missed anything while running the code but in general you can achieve what you want by using `mget` + `lapply`.

Using `mget` we can get all the models in a list and with `lapply` extract the needed statistic from it. So something like this should work for you.

```
lapply(mget(spp.names), function(x) {
  Index1 <- grep("gear",names(summary(x)$p.coeff))
  rnorm(summary(x)$p.coeff[Index1],summary(x)$se[Index1])
}) -> result

result
```

Comment: This does get the regression coefficients for each model, but doesn't solve the really cumbersome part of automating the pairwise correlation coefficients between each species pair. Thanks for giving it a try though

Comment: Yes, actually your code is not reproducible so I cannot go through each step and see what it does. As I said `summary(mod.1)$p.coeff` returns `NULL` for me.

Comment: It works for me (e.g. just running summary(mod.1)$p.coeff  ). But the end of the loop isn't working, so I changed my question to separate that part - maybe the problem more clear now?

Comment: it might be because p.coeff isn't base R, I bet it's part of the mgcv package for multivariate analysis (I'm using GAMs). I've added that to the code